# Wildcard assertions with python unittest

Tags: python, wildcard, python-unittest

Checking if there is anyway to assertEqual an object with some of the key/value being wildcarded.

I have a function, that returns an object, with one of the key being current timestamp in nanoseconds. Because this nanoseconds will change everytime I run the test, I can not expect that based on any inputs. What I want to do is to be able to call something like below

```
self.assertEqual(returnedObject, {'key1' : 'val1', 'timestampkey' : '*'} #where * being the value is wildcarded, hence dont care what is.
```

IS there any provision like this in the unittests?

What's the alternative to assert something like this.

I could perhaps assertEqual individual key/value, but wanted to prevent extra effort.

Comment: `self.assertIsNotNone(returnedObject.timestampkey)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I want to be able to assert all the other keys apart from the timestamp key, i.e. i dont care what value the timestamp key has, but I want to assert for the rest of the object.

Comment: I haven't used testing frameworks very much, so I don't know if there is support for wildcard values like you're asking for.  The closest thing I can think of is to do the `assertIsNotNone` like I commented above, then remove the `timestampkey` attribute entirely, then proceed with the full equality comparison.

Comment: ok, so you are saying that I first check that the key exists (using notnone) and then remove that from the returned object and assert for the rest of object. That makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a solution in the `unittests`. But you can check value using `regexp` or convert value to `datetime` and check types. Here is an example:

```
import time
import unittest
from datetime import datetime
import re


class Something:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.key1 = 'val1'
        self.timestampkey = time.time()


class TextExample(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        expected = dict(key1='val1')
        something = Something()
        # convert timestamp to datetime and check type
        dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(something.timestampkey)
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(dt, datetime))
        # or using regexp
        self.assertTrue(re.match(r'^\d{10}\.\d{7}$', str(something.timestampkey)))
        expected['timestampkey'] = something.timestampkey
        self.assertEqual(expected, something.__dict__)
```